# NVidia 660ti + Benq XL2730Z = distorted image and color banding

Tags: graphics-card, display

Today I finally upgraded old 19" Samsung monitor to benq xl2730z and I'm not satisfied with the experience for now. The thing is that all the images it displays are highly distorted and have pretty rough gradient. Here is the list of hardware/software I use for now:

1. Monitor Benq xl2730z (Set to 2560x1440 native resolution)
2. Nvidia GTX 660Ti (Driver version 364.51, reinstalled it twice in attempts to fix the issue. No luck)
3. Windows 10
4. Tried both DVI and Display port cables to connect monitor to my graphic card, still no luck.

Here are some pictures to discribe the issue more detailed:
[image]
[image]

I really hope that I won't have to exchange this monitor and this is not a hardware issue. Please share your thoughts about this and thank you, I appreciate your help.

**UPDATED**
I played with my monitor settings and was able to make it work much more better. Here is how the same image look like:
[image]
[image]

But, unfortunately the issue with color banding still remains and will be glad if someone can help me with this. Here are some examples:
[image]
[image]

Thanks once again.

Comment: Did the monitor ever look "normal" / did it happen right after you upgraded it? Did you reset the monitor settings to factory defaults?

Comment: @BrianC, you know, I just tried to switch back to my Samsung and in some cases it has such an issue too.. I just looked through the internet about my problem and faced this - http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=399237. It is said, that the more color output on video card the better color transition is provided. Could it be the case, I wonder?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is going to be either the system ICC profile/color management settings for the monitor or the monitor software and "auto-gaming gimmick" menu options on the monitor itself. Turn off all of the monitor's auto-gaming stuff completely, then do a basic manual color-calibration of your monitor (start button > type "color manage").

Here is an image of your screenshot when I make a simple "levels" adjustment in photo editing software. This is nearly identical to your photos.

[image]

The jpeg artifacts are from the desktop wallpaper image bundled in windows, but your system gamma (etc) is so out of whack that you can see it all. Doing a color calibration will fix banding in your games as well.

Microsoft RE: Color Calibrating ( http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/calibrate-your-display )

Comment: I'll try to do this and come back with the update, thank you so much!

Comment: Probably a good idea to check your nvidia driver control panel to set any color adjustments to default before doing the calibration.

Comment: Thank you once again for your help, I was able to get rid of the most problems, but I still have some with color banding. Please, see updated answer.

Comment: The color banding just looks like regular color banding in the OSD menu. This is by design (possibly a 16-gray-level gradient) and is not a problem. The other issue is called MOIRE and it may be adjustable in your monitor menu settings. Presuming the monitor is being driven at its native resolution, this will be something that can only be adjusted via the monitor. Maybe look for "pixel clock adjustments" but I think these are for analog connections only (?)